# Proving a fact about 4-regular graphs

Tags: graph-theory

> Prove that 4-regular graphs have no bridges.

How can I proceed? This has no solution on the textbook, and it is hard to think of any invariant or theorem involving 4-reg graphs in particular.

Comment: Do this exercise first. If you have a connected graph. And all vertices have even degree, then you have an Eulerian cycle (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path).

Comment: In problem solving it is good to be alert for information that is not really relevant to the problem. In this case $4$ is not really important for the problem. The fact that it is even is.

Comment: @RGB You should make it an answer. BTW, about what is relevant and what is not, it's not that simple, maybe it's important that $4=2^k$, or maybe it's important because planar graphs are $4$-colorable. If you don't know the necessary facts, then it's very hard to know before-hand, while it may seems obvious afterwards (see e.g. [hindsight bias](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindsight_bias)).

Comment: Yes, of course. There is no formula to determining what is relevant. I was just trying to say that it is important to be alert for when it occurs. For example, that way he doesn't restrict himself/herself in looking only for results about $4$-regular graphs and then be more open to look for results in which the resemblance is more vague.

Answer (score 1):

Let's reduce this problem a bit.  It suffices to consider $4$-regular *connected* graphs (take the connected components) and then prove that these graphs are $2$-edge connected (a graph has no bridge if and only if it has no cut edges).

As noted by RGB in the comments, the key observation here is that *even* graphs (of which $4$-regular graphs are a special case) have an Eulerian circuit.  Deleting any edge leaves us with an Eulerian trail, and so every two vertices are connected by a trail (since we can just walk along the trail between any two points).  Thus, the graph is bridgeless: the deletion of any edge leaves the graph connected.

Answer (score 0):

$E$ is the number of edges.
$d(v)$ is the degree of the vertex $v$;(it is $4$ in our case for each $v$) then
$$E = \frac12\sum_{i=1}^n d(v_i)$$
If $4$-regular graph had bridge, then removing it would create a component with some $k$ vertices,in which $d(v) = 3$ for one vertex and $d(v) = 4$ for all the others, but this can't happen as
$E = (3 + (k-1)\cdot4) /2$ is not a natural number.